# git push origin master error on Mac OS X 10.7.3

Tags: git, osx-lion, push

Hi I'm following Hartl's RoR tutorial and when trying to push my first_app directories to Git, I get the following error:

```
haseebjaved$ git push -u origin master
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

I'm on XCode 4.1, Ruby 1.9.2, Rails 3.0.11.

Same error when I omit the '-u' from the command.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Where, exactly, are you trying to push to?

Comment: I think, [search](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Permission+denied+%28publickey%29+%5Bgit%5D) is must here

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are pushing to Github, you should add your key to GitHub.

http://help.github.com/linux-set-up-git/